# Can I add a char to a variable specified position within a string?

Tags: java, string, char

OK, this is the line I am working on:

```
newstring.charAt(w) += p;
```

trying to add a character/char (p) to the string 'newstring' at a particular position within the string which is defined by int 'w'. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Strings are immutable in Java, so the answer is no. But there are many ways around it. The easiest is to create a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#StringBuilder%28java.lang.String%29) and use the [`setCharAt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt%28int,%20char%29) method. Or `insert()` if you want to insert a new character at a given position.

If you make multiple modifications to your string, you can (and indeed should) reuse your `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't modify your string, because `Strings` are immutable in Java. If you try to change the string, you will get a new string object as a result.

Now, you can use [`String#substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method for that, using which you can get `new string` which is generated by some `concatenation` of substring of original string.: -

```
str = str.substring(0, w) + "p" + str.substring(w);
```

But, of course, using `StringBuilder` as specified in @biziclop's answer is the best approach you can follow.

Comment: @JigarJoshi.. No, the first substring returns string till index `w - 1`.